# Unity Particle Systems from AssetBundle not rendered properly

Tags: unity, particles, shading, assetbundle

**Background**

I'm developing a (mobile) game that makes use of particle systems to display blood splashing. The particles are - like most assets (characters and whatnot) - world based which means there are different looking and behaving assets.

I use Assetbundles in order to keep the app's download size low, but the one's this question is about **come shipped with the app** so they're on the system after download and install.

**The Problem(s)**

There are two problems

**1. Shading**

**2. Render Order**

When I build the Assetbundles and use them in production, there seems to be a problem with the shading. The particles are not in transparent/cutoff mode and are displayed darker than usual.

Regarding the rendering order, I know there's a render feature 'sorting order' which I make use of. I have set it to a somewhat high value (higher than all my other objects) and it's still not being rendered in front of them.

For reference I've included pictures of my setups and outcomes.

**Reference Images**

This is how the particle system's assigned material appears when testing without assetbundle:

[image: particle's material when not using assetbundle]

This is how the material appears when being loaded from the assetbundle:

[image: particle's material when loaded from assetbundle]

There are two materials, but except for the sprite they share the same settings

[image: the particle material's settings]

The Assetbundle includes all of the required materials and sprites as well as the particles themselves (just to make sure)

[image: the assetbundle's composition]

When testing the particles without assetbundles (plain prefab, test build) it looks like this:

[image: what the particle system is supposed to look like]

But when built using an assetbundle, it looks like this (notice the difference in shade as well as the lack of transparency):

[image: particle system when using assetbundle]

Also, the particles are not rendered in front of other objects despite the sorting order settings:

[image: the particle system's - shared - render settings]

[image]